# Correctness of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, induction

the algorithm is intended to compute m^n for any positive integer m, n. How do i show the correctness of this algorithm through induction on n.

```
long exp(long m, int n) {

if(n == 0) return 1;

if(n == 1) return m;

if(n % 2 == 0) return exp(m*m, n/2); 

else return exp(m*m, n/2) * m;

}
```

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `P(i)` be the statement:

> `exp(m, i)` computes m<sup>i</sup> for any integer m

For the base case, it is clear that `P(0)` is true as we have `exp(m, 0) = 1 = m^0`.

For the inductive step, we assume that `P(0), P(1), ..., P(k-1)` are all true, and we claim that `P(k)` is also true. We have to consider the following three cases:

1.) If `k = 1`, then `P(1)` is clearly true as we have `exp(m, 1) = m = m^1`;

2.) If `k > 1` and `k % 2 == 0`, then by the definition of `exp` we have:

```
exp(m, k) = exp(m * m, k / 2)
```

By the induction hypothesis, we have `exp(m * m, k / 2) = (m * m)^(k / 2) = m^k`, hence `P(k)` is true in this case.

3.) If `k > 1` and `k % 2 == 1`, then by the definition of `exp` we have:

```
exp(m, k) = exp(m * m, k / 2) * m
```

By the induction hypothesis, we have `exp(m * m, k / 2) = (m * m)^(k / 2)`. Since `k % 2 == 1`, we have `k / 2 = (k - 1) / 2`. Hence we have:

```
exp(m * m, k / 2) = (m * m)^(k / 2) = (m * m)^((k-1) / 2) = m^(k-1)
```

Thus:

```
exp(m, k) = exp(m * m, k / 2) * m = m^k
```

So `P(k)` is also true in this case.